# How to install apk on android with disabled "Install from Unknown Sources "

Tags: android

Is any method that I can install application in apk file on android 12 where:

1. "Install from Unknown Sources " is disabled
2. "Developer mode" is disabled

Application is not available on google play store..

Answer (score 0):

Unless you enable Developer mode and install via adb, I'd say no. You would need to enable Install from Unknown Sources " in the settings